# Count by group and assign to the new variables

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if there's an easier way to create the variables, "freq_t1", and "freq_t2" grouped by id, from the following data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'time':[1,1,2,3,2,2]
})
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'time':[1,1,2,3,2,2],
    'freq_t1':[2,2,2,0,0,0],
    'freq_t2':[1,1,1,2,2,2]
})
```

That is, id == 1 has two observations of time == 1, while id == 2 has zero. Similarly, id == 1 has one observation of time == 2, while id == 2 has two.

Comment: Are you only looking to count t=1 and t=2? Why not t=3?

Comment: Yes. Just wanted to know how to create a new variable of counting particular values from a different column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use broadcasted comparison on the "time" column with your selected time values, then `groupby` and `transform` to broadcast the sum to the original columns. Here's an example:

```
tvals = [1, 2]
(pd.DataFrame(df['time'].values[:,None] == tvals, columns=tvals)
   .groupby(df['id'])
   .transform('sum')
   .astype(int)
   .add_prefix('freq_t'))

   freq_t1  freq_t2
0        2        1
1        2        1
2        2        1
3        0        2
4        0        2
5        0        2
```

When `tvals = [1, 2, 3]`, this produces

```
   freq_t1  freq_t2  freq_t3
0        2        1        0
1        2        1        0
2        2        1        0
3        0        2        1
4        0        2        1
5        0        2        1
```

---

If you want columns for all t-values, you can also use `get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.time).groupby(df.id).transform('sum').add_prefix('freq_t')

   freq_t1  freq_t2  freq_t3
0        2        1        0
1        2        1        0
2        2        1        0
3        0        2        1
4        0        2        1
5        0        2        1
```

Finally, to concatenate the result to `df`, use `pd.concat`:

```
res = pd.get_dummies(df.time).groupby(df.id).transform('sum').add_prefix('freq_t')
pd.concat([df, res], axis=1)

   id  time  freq_t1  freq_t2  freq_t3
0   1     1        2        1        0
1   1     1        2        1        0
2   1     2        2        1        0
3   2     3        0        2        1
4   2     2        0        2        1
5   2     2        0        2        1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just adding onto your solution, would there be more straightforward way (to me who just switched from R to python), such as `df['freq_t1'] = df.groupby('id')....` with some clause like `df.time == 1`?

Comment: @jayc I should mention you concatenate this result with the original by doing `df = pd.concat([df, this_result], axis=1)`. There are other ways but IMO this is the simplest. Let me know if you have any other questions.